# line order number start numbering from second line (SOLVED)

Tags: taxonomy, order, count, list

[image]

```
if(is_tax())
                    {
                        $currentTermType = get_query_var( 'taxonomy' );
                        $cat_icon = get_field('logo', $queried_object);
                        $termId= get_queried_object()->term_id;
                         if(is_tax($currentTermType) && $termId==$term->term_id)
                          $carrentActiveClass='class="active-cat"';
                          $i=0;

                    }    
                        $icon = get_field('logo', $term->taxonomy . '_' . $term->term_id); 
                        $va_category_HTML .= '<li class="logolar" '.$carrentActiveClass.'>' .'<a class="rownum">' .$i++. '</a>'. '</a>';
                        $va_category_HTML .= sprintf('<img src="%s" />', $icon) . '</a>';
                        $va_category_HTML .='<a href="' . esc_url( $term_link ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
                        if (empty( $instance['wcw_hide_count'] )) {
                        $va_category_HTML .='<span class="post-count">'.$term->count.'</span>';
                        }

                        $va_category_HTML .='</li>';
                    }
```

this is my code

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: i want numbering start from first line..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you started your index at 1, instead of 0?

Change: `$i=0;`
To: `$i=1;`

You might have checked, but you aren't having an CSS / layout issues, are you?

Comment: problem was that i had wrote $i=0; code inside of if condition and thats way my code did not work.. i locate this code out of if condition and it worked

Comment: Glad you figured it out!